# How do you specify a specific UIScrollView to scroll to the top

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a view with multiple UIScrollViews on it. Because of this, tapping the header bar does not scroll to the top of any scroller. Is their a way to specify a specific scroller in my view to scroll to the top when the tap occurres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go through all your other scroll views, and set their `scrollsToTop` property to NO. The scrollview you want to scroll up needs to be the only one with this property set to YES.

From [the UIScrollView.scrollsToTop docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html):

> The scroll-to-top gesture is a tap on the status bar; when this
>   property is YES, the scroll view jumps to the top of the content when
>   this gesture occurs. The default value of this property is YES.
>
> This gesture works on a single visible scroll view; if there are
>   multiple scroll views (for example, a date picker) with this property
>   set, or if the delegate returns NO in scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:,
>   UIScrollView ignores the request.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that out. I had originally read that document to mean that if you had more than one scroller you just could not scroll to the top for any of them.

Answer (score 1):

`[myView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];`

or

`[myScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];`

Comment: I could only do this if I intersect the header bar tap. Their is already support in the scroll view to do this and I was wondering what setting configuration needed to be used.